# Using remote true with a different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a structure that looks like this :

**modifications**

- _form
- _miniform
- index

My index shows something like :

```
  %span.right
    = render "modifications/form", modification: modification
```

Form and Miniform are almost identical:

```
.modification-forms
  - if can? :reject, modification.model
    = form_tag modification_rejections_url, class: "inline", remote: true do |f|
      = hidden_field_tag :id, modification.model.id
      = submit_button "Reject", class: 'btn btn-danger'

  - if can? :approve, modification.model
    = form_tag modification_approvals_url, class: "inline", remote: true do |f|
      = hidden_field_tag :id, modification.model.id
      = submit_button "Approve" , class: 'btn btn-success'
```

vs miniform

```
.modification-device-forms
  - if can? :reject, modification.model
    = form_tag modification_rejections_url, class: "inline", remote: true do |f|
      = hidden_field_tag :id, modification.model.id
      = submit_button "<i class='icon-remove'> </i>".html_safe

  - if can? :approve, modification.model
    = form_tag modification_approvals_url, class: "inline", remote: true do |f|
      = hidden_field_tag :id, modification.model.id
      = submit_button "<i class='icon-ok'> </i>".html_safe
```

When i render the _form partial, ajax performs how you would expect.  After clicking a button, the row disappears.

However, when I swap in miniform, it no longer works.  The ajax runs, but it doesn't delete the row.

I assume this is rails conventions getting mixed up, but im not so good with rails magic, and have no idea where to start in deciphering this.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I suspect the bootstrap icon should be shown as
`= submit_button do
  %i.icon-remove
end`